# How to erase the O[x] terms after using Series

Tags: series-expansion

I have a matrix in which I have used terms like:

```
Series[Sin[(a qy)/2] , {qy, 0, 2}]
```

How to get rid of the `O[qz]^3` afterwards ?

Comment: Look up Normal in the help files.